# inserting multiple rows to table in database codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert multiple rows to my database using a single query. I saw lots of questions related to this but they dont work for me.

I was able to save the multiple rows but the values are all the same, its the last data that i inputted so i guess i missed something?

Here are the codes:

Controller

```
public function addgrade()
{
    $recordid = $this->input->post('recordid');
    $studentid = $this->input->post('studentid');
    $compid = $this->input->post('compid');
    $subcompid = $this->input->post('subcompid');
    $grade = $this->input->post('grade');
    $classid = $this->input->post('classid');


    foreach($this->UserModel->students() as $student):
        if ($student->classid==$classid) { //$classid==33
            $i=0;
            $data = array(
                    'recordid' =>$recordid,
                    'studentid' => $studentid,
                    'compid' => $compid,
                    'subcompid' =>$subcompid,
                    'grade' =>$grade
                );

            $this->Crud->addgrade($data);

        }
    endforeach;
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Successfully created!');
    redirect('instructor');
}
```

Model

```
public function addgrade($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('grade', $data);
}
```

View

```
<td>
   <strong>
       <input class="form-control inputScore" type="hidden" name="classid" value="<?php echo $classid;?>"></input>
       <input class="form-control inputScore" type="hidden" name="recordid" value="<?php echo $record->id;?>"></input>
       <input class="form-control inputScore" type="hidden" name="studentid" value="<?php echo $student->studentid;?>"></input>
       <input class="form-control inputScore" type="hidden" name="compid" value="<?php echo $subcomp->id;?>"></input>
       <input class="form-control inputScore" type="hidden" name="subcompid" value="<?php echo $subcomp->id;?>"></input>
       <input class="form-control inputScore" type="text" name="grade"></input>
   </strong></td>
```

All that gave me is this output on my database:

[image]

Comment: Yo dont have multiple inputs so why do you think you need to do multiple inserts into the database

Comment: Or maybe you are not showing us enough of your HTML

Comment: i suppose i can get the values of hidden input types and insert it in their respective variables? Is that not right?

Comment: That part is just fine

Comment: But you only have one set of input data. Then you get ALL your student rows and Insert the input data Number of student times to the same student id

Comment: wait, the <td> is actually inside a foreach thing where it gets all my 6 students, so i get 6 inputs -- my bad

Comment: Then you need to name them as arrays like this `name="classid[]"`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this instead? There's more detailed info about it here... [Codeigniter - Append rows in view then add those rows to database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968370/codeigniter-append-rows-in-view-then-add-those-rows-to-database-table)

```
$this->db->insert_batch('grade', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form code, for all of your "name" variables such as name="classid", be sure to add "[]" at the end... name="classid[]"